# Grails GORM: Change foreign key column name

Tags: grails, grails-orm, join

I'm trying to change the foreign key column name that is used in `Visitor` table for `User`'s id. The column is named now `user_id`, I want to change that to `who_id`.

**Minimal `User` Domain Class:**

```
class User {

    static hasMany = [
        visitor: Visitor
    ]

    String uid

    ...

}
```

**Minimal `Visitor` Domain Class:**

```
class Visitor {

  static belongsTo = [user: User]

  ....

}
```

## Question:

I've tried with `mappedBy` but with no success, is there another way to use a property from `User` as a foreign key in `Visitor`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to use the mapping static block:

```
class Visitor {
  static belongsTo = [user: User]
  static mapping = { user column: 'who_id' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the uid in User as the id (primary key). That will make it automatically the foreign key in the Visitors domain.

```
class User {

String uid

static mapping = {
    id column: 'uid'
}
...
```